# VBA macro for copying data from multiple word files to excel

Tags: vba

I have got the below code but it is showing run process status only not even getting an error.
Please can anyone help me in it.

```
Sub Copy_Data_From_Multiple_WordFiles()

Dim FolderName As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim NewWordFile As New Word.Application
Dim NewDoc As New Word.Document

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FolderName = "C:\Users\1040804\Desktop\BCS Data Check\"
FileName = Dir(FolderName)

'Loop start

Do While FileName <> ""

    Set NewDoc = NewWordFile.documents.Open(FolderName & FileName)
    
    NewDoc.Range(0, NewDoc.Range.End).Copy
    Range("LastRow").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    NewDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    NewWordFile.Quit
    
FileName = Dir()

Loop

End Sub
```

It is running the above code but no output file is copying into the excel.

Comment: Please add more detail about what should be happening and what the result should be.  Please also state which application you are using to generate the VBA (Excel or Word).

Comment: Hi,I am using Excel application